# Hidden line at the end of the ms word table causes empty space at the end

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-table

If I have multiple lines in word table and hide lines in between then ms word shows no empty space, but if I hide line(s) which are at the last, then ms word shows empty line. Please refer image in below link.

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "hide lines". It would help if you'd turn on the display of non-printing characters and re-take the screen shots you provide. Also, how is this a programming question? You tag with `openxml` - please provide the relevant Office Open XML for the problem as well as the code being used to produce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=938582) (tek-tips.com) can provide you with some extra info. At the end of the last paragraph in a table cell, the Microsoft Word Office application will insert a [BELL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) (wikipedia) character (can be considered as an extra paragagraph) to define the instersection between two table cells. Hiding this character would thus 'hide' this intersection and is thus not possible.

So you can 'hide' the last paragraph either:

- Removing the last paragraph
- Giving the font a white color and setting it as small ass possible (1)